# Is there any way to print multiple lines in JS alert box using loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, alert

Hey guys I want to ask if there is any way to write multiple lines in one JS alert box using for loop? [image: I WANT TO HAVE OUTPUT LIKE THIS WITH ONE STRING VARIABLE AND ANY LOOP]

I WANT TO HAVE OUTPUT LIKE THIS WITH ONE STRING VARIABLE AND ANY LOOP,
HOW CAN I HAVE OUTPUT LIKE THIS WITH ABOVE MENTIONED REQUIREMENTS?

Comment: Not reliably, no. The ECMAScript specification does not describe how `alert()` boxes should appear. Long messages will be truncated. Also, using the old-school message-boxes like `alert()`, `confirm()` and `prompt()` are discouraged because they block the UI thread. Consider using HTML5's `<dialog>` instead.

Comment: try using 3rd party alert like sweetalert 
https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

Use \n

alert("String 1\nString 2");

```js
var p = '';

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  p+= "string " + i + '\n'
}

alert(p)
```